# How do I do animated number by adding value each second

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

How do I do animated number by adding value each second. Like in this plugin
http://aishek.github.io/jquery-animateNumber

Html

```
<div class="earned">171655.10457862</div>
```

Here is jQuery code

```
var DOGEbal = 171655.10457862;
var per_second = 1.56948984;
interval = setInterval(function(){
  DOGEbal += per_second;
  DOGEbalStack = DOGEbal.toString();
  DOGEbalStack = DOGEbalStack.slice(0, (DOGEbalStack.indexOf("."))+9);
  $(".earned").html(DOGEbalStack);
}, 1000);
```

So I would like to animate number adding `per_second` to `.earned`. Doing that each second like in animateNumber plugin

Here is https://jsfiddle.net/uzd83qw6/1/ example. How to animate that example?

Comment: Not sure what your question is here. That fiddle example has an "animated" number that increases every second.

Comment: @Jeto That's example in fiddle is not animated. Please look at example of extension. That's animated. In fiddle just increasing each second...

Comment: There is no animation here. What you want is to write every number between current and next number. You just need a loop that goes from current to the next and print it.

Comment: Just replace the 1000 with 10 and the 1.5xxx with 0.015xxx and it will be animated

Comment: The fact that the number changes through all intermediate numbers gives an impression of movement, hence animation. It just prints lots of numbers before printing the final number.

Comment: @NawedKhan That's what I am looking for. How to implement that's in current example. More easy and smooth way. I found extensions from 0 to some value. But not for adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take your "per second step" and transform it into a "per millisecond" delay:

```js
function animate($target, fromValue, incrementPerSecond) {
  var incrementPerMillisecond = incrementPerSecond / 1000;
  var currentValue = fromValue;

  $target.text(currentValue);
  setInterval(function () {
    $target.text((currentValue + incrementPerMillisecond).toFixed(8));
    currentValue += incrementPerMillisecond;
  }, 1);
}

animate($('.earned'), 171655.10457862, 1.56948984);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="earned"></div>
```

Comment: `incrementPerSecond / 10` and `setInterval to 100` seems to be better. Thank u